# What is this grill-like thing on my chain link fence?

Tags: fence, shelving

New house, just found this in far backyard, behind a tree and under a jungle of vine weeds I ripped out. Seems like an odd place. What might it be, or used for?

[image: Grill-like thing]

[image: Base of grill-like thing]

Comment: Looks like an old fridge shelf, repurposed for an shelf, maybe was a garden near there.

Comment: For grape or berry vines.

Comment: Definitely repurposed since it is mounted upside down. (The reinforcing rod in the center should be on the bottom.) The previous owner could have used it for any moderately "loaded" purpose, e.g. playing chess with a neighbor over the fence with room enough for beers. Perhaps a place to reload so the squirrels don't get all the food. The timbers below _ought_ to rule out anything involving large fires.

Comment: If there is a path on the outside, it could be some kind of "take some garden-goods and put some coin into this piggy-bank, we have too much to use all up this year"?

Answer (score 1):

Shelf for trays with feed and water for birds?

EDIT
Shelf for potted plants? (Dog has been savaging potted plants.)

Comment: I don't think so, squirrels would get all the bird feed.

Comment: Potting shelf?    BBQ grill?